# How to hide a column that is build by divs either in server side or client side in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i made a table like design with div.
here is sample html

```
<div class='header-row'>
     <div class='first-column'>
     <div class='second-column'>
     <div class='third-column'>
     <div class='fourth-column'>
</div>

<div class='normal-row'>
<div class='first-column'>
     <div class='second-column'>
     <div class='third-column'>
     <div class='fourth-column'>
</div>
```

how can i hide the third column either in server side or in client side.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to close your DIVs. Sample code is below:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
  {
     $('.third-column').hide();
  });
```

Comment: And since the DIVs are not made server side, you cannot hide them from the server side.

Comment: yes that works. what about server side if set them to server side.

Comment: see my comment, you need to set this attribute runat="server" id="divID" to be able to access it from code-behind in Asp.Net